# Where can I exchange Georgian Lari in the United States?

Tags: usa, money, georgia-country, exchange

I have some Georgian Lari and I'm going to the US in a couple of weeks and was wondering if anyone knew any outlets in either Los Angeles, San Francisco, Las Vegas, Dallas, Austin, New Orleans, Nashville, Memphis or New York City where I could exchange it for US dollars?

So hard to find anywhere that changes it over!

I wish I knew before I left Georgia!

Comment: also it doesn't have to be in these cities but i figure if it's anywhere it'll be in either of these places

Comment: Which cities will you be in? Just LA and NYC? I'd update the title to specify, just so it doesn't get closed as "too broad".

Answer (score 6):

If you have an amount of money so great that it would be a real loss not to change it to US dollars I have a suggestion.

There is a program placing native English speakers as teachers all around Georgia, called [Teach and Learn with Georgia](http://www.tlg.gov.ge/) (TLG). If you can find somebody living in your city who is about to go teach with TLG then I'm sure they would be very happy to exchange some money with you directly.

One possible way to find such people might be the Facebook group used mainly by TLG'ers called [*Georgian Wanderers*](https://www.facebook.com/groups/Georgianwanderers/). TLG also has a [Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/TLGeorgia).

Answer (score 4):

You may have to physically walk in to [Travelex](http://www.travelex.com/) or any other currency exchange places to attempt to do this.

I've checked the online versions of [Travelex](http://www.travelex.com/), [American Express](https://travel.americanexpress.com/travel/currency-converter), [Bank of America](https://www4.bankofamerica.com/foreigncurrency/exchgforeigncurrency.action), [Wells Fargo](https://www.wellsfargo.com/foreignexchange/) and they don't provide Georgian Lari for sale online, so that usually means that the requests for exchange of that currency are rare enough not to keep any on hand.

[Travelex](http://www.travelex.com/) lists a phone number you can call to see if they will exchange your Lari, but I wouldn't hold my breath for one and two the exchange rate you will get in the US will be much worse then what you might have gotten in Georgia.